# Find the posterior probability density function

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have an observation $z={x\over y}$. I have the probability density functions
$$pdf(y)=\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1y}, y\geq0$$
$$pdf(x)=\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2x}, x\geq0$$
I found that the probability density function of $z$ is
$$pdf(z)={\lambda_1\lambda_2\over{(\lambda_2z+\lambda_1)^2}}$$
or I can express this as
$$pdf(z={x\over y})={\lambda_1\lambda_2\over{(\lambda_2{x\over y}+\lambda_1)^2}}$$. The posterior probability density function is
$$pdf(x|z)={pdf(z|x)pdf(x)\over pdf(z)}$$. How do I compute the conditional probability density function 
$$pdf(z|x)=?$$

Is it
$$pdf(z|x)={pdf(z)\over pdf(x)}$$

Comment: if $y$ is a sample from the random variables $Y$ with pdf defined above, then the density of $(z|x)$ is the density of $Y$ at the point $\frac{x}{z}$ because $ y =\frac{x}{z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U=X$ and $Z=X/Y.$ We can compute the joint distribution of $U$ and $Z$ (which is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Z$ of course... we just renamed $X$ $U$ to avoid confusion) in the usual way with a change of variables: $$ X=U\;\;\;\;\;Y=U/Z\\ J = \pmatrix{1& 1/Z\\0& -U/Z^2}\\f_{U,Z}(u,z) = |J|f_{X,Y}(u,u/z) = \frac{u}{z^2} \lambda_2\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_2u}e^{-\lambda_1u/z}$$ and we'll just call $u$ $x$ from now on.

As you correctly computed, $$ f_Z(z) = \frac{\lambda_1\lambda_2}{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2 z)^2},$$ so we have by definition of conditional density, $$ f_{X\mid Z} (x\mid z)= \frac{f_{X,Z}(x,z)}{f_Z(z)}=\frac{\frac{x}{z^2} \lambda_2\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_2x}e^{-\lambda_1x/z}}{\frac{\lambda_1\lambda_2}{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2 z)^2}}= x(\lambda_2+\lambda_1/z)^2e^{-(\lambda_2+\lambda_1/z)x},$$ a Gamma distribution.

To find the $x$ that maximizes this, observe it is proportional to $xe^{-ax}$ where $a=(\lambda_2+\lambda_1/z).$ The derivative is $e^{-ax}-axe^{-ax},$ which is zero at $x=1/a,$ so the mode of the conditional distribution for $x$ given $z$ is $ \frac{1}{(\lambda_2+\lambda_1/z)}.$

Comment: Thank you. Your result makes sense, but when I put everything together to compute the posterior probability density function and try to find $x$ value which maximizes the posterior probability density function I get some weird results. Is my posterior probability defined correctly?

Comment: @Don I edited cause it looks like you are interested in $x$ conditional on $z$ rather than the other way around (I also fixed the switched $\lambda$'s.) I don't see anything glaringly weird or wrong about the result it gives for the mode, though it's not one of those where it is intuitively obvious to me that it has to be correct.

Comment: But don't we need to plug in z=x/y before we take the derivative of $f_{X|Z}(x|z)$?

Comment: @Don No, we don't and should not.

Comment: isn't z dependent on x? If I take a derivative with respect to x shouldn't I take ${dz\over dx}$ as z is a function of x? Do you see my confusion here?

Comment: @Don Yes I see it. $z$ is fixed though... we are saying "we observed $z=2$ (or whatever), now let's see what the distribution of the unknown $x$ looks like now." We pass along the information for how $Z$ is influenced by $X$ when we compute the joint/conditional distribution.

Comment: @Don Perhaps another way to convince yourself: the random variable Z is a function of $X$ (and $Y$), sure. But these variables we parametrize these density functions with certainly bear no functional relationship to one another (that couldn't possibly even mean anything). Then you need to think, "what does $f(x\mid z)$ *mean*.. it's our information about the distribution for $X$ given that we've seen the value that $Z$ realized at. It's just a function of $x$ that integrates to one... the $z$ is just a parameter saying which value of $Z$ realized...

Comment: @Don ... so if we want the maximum of this distribution for $x$, we just maximize it in $x$... this will be different for different values of $z$ because different values of $z$ communicate different information about $x,$ but thinking $z$ somehow depends on $x$ here is confusing $x$ (the variable we are using in the density function) with the random variable $X.$

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: How do you get your determinant like that? Isn't it the first row of your Jacobean matrix $${\partial\over\partial u}  u, {\partial\over\partial z}  u?$$

Comment: @Don If the matrix were transposed would it be what you get? If so, it doesn’t matter since transposing preserves the determinant

Comment: Thanks. I got this